# Jupyter Runs Line, Stuck on "In [*]" with np.genfromtxt, doesn't define the list

Tags: python, numpy, jupyter-notebook, genfromtxt

I am trying to read in a data file using np.genfromtxt. I've used this method for other input files which are larger, so I'm not sure why it isn't working now. My suspicion is that I'm running out of RAM, but even when closing other windows and minimizing what my computer is doing, it still won't finish the cell and define the array.

You can see that it tries to run the code normally, but will act like it's done, yet the input cell still has an asterisk as if it isn't completed.

The line is simply:

```
    pddata = np.genfromtxt('/Users/nathan/Research/0_Personal/22_new/pddata.dat', delimiter=" ", dtype=(float,int,int,int,int,int,"|S10",float,float,float))
```

[The cell after it has been run can be seen here.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BucNy.png)

I understand this issue is usually an infinite loop question, however I'm not sure how to fix the internal loop from numpy. I considered it may be a data type issue, although I'm fairly certain the defined datatypes are correct.

Comment: please post the code as text, not a screenshot.

Comment: If it works for other files, but not this, and the file layout is the same, the code won't help.  It looks normal.  Size could be the issue, but I haven't used notebooks that much.  Could you  try this load from a `ipython` session?  Or a plain python script?

Comment: @hpaulj running in ipython helped. It throws an error that the input file had inconsistent column lengths, so I fixed that and now it's running fine. Thanks for the help!!